# SQL Query results into a already created table

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, sql-insert

I need some help getting the results from this query:

```
SELECT 
    a.RouteNumber, b.DPS - a.BaseDPS AS DiffDPS, 
    b.Flats - a.BaseFlats AS DiffFlats, 
    b.Parcels - a.BaseParcels AS DiffParcels 
FROM 
    Sheet1$ b
INNER JOIN 
    RouteInfo a ON b.RouteNumber = a.RouteNumber
```

To go into a table I have already created (`Routegen`). `Routegen` already has the columns (RouteNumber, DPS, Flats, Parcels).

I've tried using `SELECT INTO`, but apparently I'm not doing it right because I can't get the code to run after changing it.

The main goal here is to compare then subtract data from both tables and put it into a new table. I feel like I'm close, just need a little help!

Thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `insert ... select`:

```
INSERT INTO Routegen (RouteNumber, DPS, Flats, Parcels)
SELECT a.RouteNumber, b.DPS - a.BaseDPS, b.Flats - a.BaseFlats, b.Parcels - a.BaseParcels
FROM Sheet1$ b
INNER JOIN RouteInfo a ON b.RouteNumber=a.RouteNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your query and based on your goal, you could select into a temp table to query and analyze your data:

```
SELECT a.RouteNumber, b.DPS - a.BaseDPS as DiffDPS, b.Flats-a.BaseFlats as DiffFlats, b.Parcels-a.BaseParcels as DiffParcels
into #tmpRoutegen
FROM Sheet1$ b
INNER JOIN RouteInfo a
ON b.RouteNumber=a.RouteNumber
```

If you need to add it into the original table then the above answer from GMB should suffice.